# How to remove loading effect in particle slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

There is a loading effect which I want to remove from the below given Interactive particle logo.
The attempted code and codepen URL are as follows.

https://codepen.io/Zaku/pen/EDaun[Codepent Interactive Particle Logo](https://codepen.io/Zaku/pen/EDaun)

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ParticleSlider</title>
  </head>
  <body id="particle-slider">
      <div class="slides">
        <div id="first-slide" class="slide" data-src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        </div>
        </div>
        <canvas class="draw"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
var init = function(){
  var isMobile = navigator.userAgent &&
    navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile') >= 0;
  var isSmall = window.innerWidth < 1000;

  var ps = new ParticleSlider({
    ptlGap: isMobile || isSmall ? 3 : 0,
    ptlSize: isMobile || isSmall ? 3 : 1,
    width: 1e9,
    height: 1e9
  });

  var gui = new dat.GUI();
  gui.add(ps, 'ptlGap').min(0).max(5).step(1).onChange(function(){
    ps.init(true);
  });
  gui.add(ps, 'ptlSize').min(1).max(5).step(1).onChange(function(){
    ps.init(true);
  });
  gui.add(ps, 'restless');
  gui.addColor(ps, 'color').onChange(function(value){
    ps.monochrome = true;
    ps.setColor(value);
      ps.init(true);
  });


  (window.addEventListener
   ? window.addEventListener('click', function(){ps.init(true)}, false)
   : window.onclick = function(){ps.init(true)});
}

var initParticleSlider = function(){
  var psScript = document.createElement('script');
  (psScript.addEventListener
    ? psScript.addEventListener('load', init, false)
    : psScript.onload = init);
  psScript.src = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/23500/ps-0.9.js';
    psScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  document.body.appendChild(psScript);
}

(window.addEventListener
  ? window.addEventListener('load', initParticleSlider, false)
  : window.onload = initParticleSlider);
```

I wanted to make a logo exactly like this but without loading effect on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function ParticleSlider(a) {
    var b = this;
    b.sliderId = "particle-slider", b.color = "#fff", b.hoverColor = "#88f", b.width = 0, b.height = 20, b.ptlGap = 0, b.ptlSize = 1, b.slideDelay = 10, b.arrowPadding = 10, b.showArrowControls = !0, b.onNextSlide = null, b.onWidthChange = null, b.onHeightChange = null, b.onSizeChange = null, b.monochrome = !1, b.mouseForce = 1e4, b.restless = !0, b.imgs = [];
    if (a) {
        var c = ["color", "hoverColor", "width", "height", "ptlGap", "ptlSize", "slideDelay", "arrowPadding", "sliderId", "showArrowControls", "onNextSlide", "monochrome", "mouseForce", "restless", "imgs", "onSizeChange", "onWidthChange", "onHeightChange"];
        for (var d = 0, e = c.length; d < e; d++) a[c[d]] && (b[c[d]] = a[c[d]])
    }
    b.$container = b.$("#" + b.sliderId), b.$$children = b.$container.childNodes, b.$controlsContainer = b.$(".controls"), b.$$slides = b.$(".slide", b.$(".slides").childNodes, !0), b.$controlLeft = null, b.$controlRight = null, b.$canv = b.$(".draw"), b.$srcCanv = document.createElement("canvas"), b.$srcCanv.style.display = "none", b.$container.appendChild(b.$srcCanv), b.$prevCanv = document.createElement("canvas"), b.$prevCanv.style.display = "none", b.$container.appendChild(b.$prevCanv), b.$nextCanv = document.createElement("canvas"), b.$nextCanv.style.display = "none", b.$container.appendChild(b.$nextCanv), b.$overlay = document.createElement("p"), b.$container.appendChild(b.$overlay), b.imgControlPrev = null, b.imgControlNext = null, b.$$slides.length <= 1 && (b.showArrowControls = !1), b.$controlsContainer && b.$controlsContainer.childNodes && b.showArrowControls == !0 ? (b.$controlLeft = b.$(".left", b.$controlsContainer.childNodes), b.$controlRight = b.$(".right", b.$controlsContainer.childNodes), b.imgControlPrev = new Image, b.imgControlNext = new Image, b.imgControlPrev.onload = function () {
        b.$prevCanv.height = this.height, b.$prevCanv.width = this.width, b.loadingStep()
    },
        b.imgControlNext.onload = function () {
            b.$nextCanv.height = this.height, b.$nextCanv.width = this.width, b.loadingStep()
        },
        b.imgControlPrev.src = b.$controlLeft.getAttribute("data-src"), b.imgControlNext.src = b.$controlRight.getAttribute("data-src")) : b.showArrowControls = !1, b.width <= 0 && (b.width = b.$container.clientWidth), b.height <= 0 && (b.height = b.$container.clientHeight), b.mouseDownRegion = 0, b.colorArr = b.parseColor(b.color), b.hoverColorArr = b.parseColor(b.hoverColor), b.mx = -1, b.my = -1, b.swipeOffset = 0, b.cw = b.getCw(), b.ch = b.getCh(), b.frame = 0, b.nextSlideTimer = !1, b.currImg = 0, b.lastImg = 0, b.imagesLoaded = 0, b.pxlBuffer = {
            first: null
        },
        b.recycleBuffer = {
            first: null
        }, b.ctx = b.$canv.getContext("2d"), b.srcCtx = b.$srcCanv.getContext("2d"), b.prevCtx = b.$prevCanv.getContext("2d"), b.nextCtx = b.$nextCanv.getContext("2d"), b.$canv.width = b.cw, b.$canv.height = b.ch, b.shuffle = function () {
            var a, b;
            for (var c = 0, d = this.length; c < d; c++) b = Math.floor(Math.random() * d), a = this[c], this[c] = this[b], this[b] = a
        }, Array.prototype.shuffle = b.shuffle, b.$canv.onmouseout = function () {
            b.mx = -1, b.my = -1, b.mouseDownRegion = 0
        }, b.$canv.onmousemove = function (a) {
            function c(a) {
                var c = 0,
                    d = 0,
                    e = typeof a == "string" ? b.$(a) : a;
                if (e) {
                    c = e.offsetLeft, d = e.offsetTop;
                    var f = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                    while (e.offsetParent && e != f) c += e.offsetParent.offsetLeft, d += e.offsetParent.offsetTop, e = e.offsetParent
                }
                this.x = c, this.y = d
            }
            var d = new c(b.$container);
            b.mx = a.clientX - d.x + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft, b.my = a.clientY - d.y + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop
        }, b.$canv.onmousedown = function () {
            if (b.imgs.length > 1) {
                var a = 0;
                b.mx >= 0 && b.mx < b.arrowPadding * 2 + b.$prevCanv.width ? a = -1 : b.mx > 0 && b.mx > b.cw - (b.arrowPadding * 2 + b.$nextCanv.width) && (a = 1), b.mouseDownRegion = a
            }
        }, b.$canv.onmouseup = function () {
            if (b.imgs.length > 1) {
                var a = "";
                b.mx >= 0 && b.mx < b.arrowPadding * 2 + b.$prevCanv.width ? a = -1 : b.mx > 0 && b.mx > b.cw - (b.arrowPadding * 2 + b.$nextCanv.width) && (a = 1), a != 0 && b.mouseDownRegion != 0 && (a != b.mouseDownRegion && (a *= -1), b.nextSlideTimer && clearTimeout(b.nextSlideTimer), b.nextSlide(a)), b.mouseDownRegion = 0
            }
        };
    if (b.imgs.length == 0)
        for (var d = 0, e = b.$$slides.length; d < e; d++) {
            var f = new Image;
            b.imgs.push(f), f.src = b.$$slides[d].getAttribute("data-src")
        }
    b.imgs.length > 0 && (b.imgs[0].onload = function () {
        b.loadingStep()
    }), b.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        b.nextFrame()
    })
}
var psParticle = function (a) {
    this.ps = a, this.ttl = null, this.color = a.colorArr, this.next = null, this.prev = null, this.gravityX = 0, this.gravityY = 0, this.x = 0, this.y = 0, this.velocityX = 0, this.velocityY = 0
};
psParticle.prototype.move = function () {
    var a = this.ps,
        b = this;
    if (this.ttl != null && this.ttl-- <= 0) a.swapList(b, a.pxlBuffer, a.recycleBuffer), this.ttl = null;
    else {
        var c = this.gravityX + a.swipeOffset - this.x,
            d = this.gravityY - this.y,
            e = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2) + Math.pow(d, 2)),
            f = Math.atan2(d, c),
            g = e * .01;
        a.restless == !0 ? g = 0 : (this.x = this.gravityX - 60, this.y = this.gravityY);
        var h = 0,
            i = 0;
        if (a.mx >= 0 && a.mouseForce) {
            var j = this.x - a.mx,
                k = this.y - a.my;
            h = Math.min(a.mouseForce / (Math.pow(j, 2) + Math.pow(k, 2)), a.mouseForce), i = Math.atan2(k, j), typeof this.color == "function" && (i += Math.PI, h *= .001 + Math.random() * .1 - .05)
        } else h = 0, i = 0;
        this.velocityX += g * Math.cos(f) + h * Math.cos(i), this.velocityY += g * Math.sin(f) + h * Math.sin(i), this.velocityX *= .92, this.velocityY *= .92, this.x += this.velocityX, this.y += this.velocityY
    }
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.Particle = psParticle, ParticleSlider.prototype.swapList = function (a, b, c) {
    var d = this;
    a == null ? a = new d.Particle(d) : b.first == a ? a.next != null ? (a.next.prev = null, b.first = a.next) : b.first = null : a.next == null ? a.prev.next = null : (a.prev.next = a.next, a.next.prev = a.prev), c.first == null ? (c.first = a, a.prev = null, a.next = null) : (a.next = c.first, c.first.prev = a, c.first = a, a.prev = null)
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.parseColor = function (a) {
    var b, a = a.replace(" ", "");
    if (b = /^#([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})/.exec(a)) b = [parseInt(b[1], 16), parseInt(b[2], 16), parseInt(b[3], 16)];
    else if (b = /^#([\da-fA-F])([\da-fA-F])([\da-fA-F])/.exec(a)) b = [parseInt(b[1], 16) * 17, parseInt(b[2], 16) * 17, parseInt(b[3], 16) * 17];
    else if (b = /^rgba\(([\d]+),([\d]+),([\d]+),([\d]+|[\d]*.[\d]+)\)/.exec(a)) b = [+b[1], +b[2], +b[3], +b[4]];
    else if (b = /^rgb\(([\d]+),([\d]+),([\d]+)\)/.exec(a)) b = [+b[1], +b[2], +b[3]];
    else return null;
    isNaN(b[3]) && (b[3] = 1), b[3] *= 255;
    return b
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.loadingStep = function () {
    var a = this;
    a.imagesLoaded++;
    if (a.imagesLoaded >= 3 || a.showArrowControls == !1) a.resize(), a.slideDelay > 0 && (a.nextSlideTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        a.nextSlide()
    }, 1e3 * a.slideDelay))
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.$ = function (a, b, c) {
    var d = this;
    if (a[0] == ".") {
        var e = a.substr(1);
        b || (b = d.$$children);
        var f = [];
        for (var g = 0, h = b.length; g < h; g++) b[g].className && b[g].className == e && f.push(b[g]);
        return f.length == 0 ? null : f.length == 1 && !c ? f[0] : f
    }
    return document.getElementById(a.substr(1))
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.nextFrame = function () {
    var a = this;
    a.mouseDownRegion == 1 && a.mx < a.cw / 2 || a.mouseDownRegion == -1 && a.mx > a.cw / 2 ? a.swipeOffset = a.mx - a.cw / 2 : a.swipeOffset = 0;
    var b = a.pxlBuffer.first,
        c = null;
    while (b != null) c = b.next, b.move(), b = c;
    a.drawParticles();
    if (a.frame++ % 25 == 0 && (a.cw != a.getCw() || a.ch != a.getCh())) {
        var d = a.getCh(),
            e = a.getCw();
        a.ch != e && typeof a.onWidthChange == "function" && a.onWidthChange(a, e), a.ch != d && typeof a.onHeightChange == "function" && a.onHeightChange(a, d), typeof a.onSizeChange == "function" && a.onSizeChange(a, e, d), a.resize()
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        a.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            a.nextFrame()
        })
    }, 15)
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.nextSlide = function (a) {
    var b = this;
    b.nextSlideTimer != null && b.imgs.length > 1 ? (b.currImg = (b.currImg + b.imgs.length + (a ? a : 1)) % b.imgs.length, b.resize(), b.slideDelay > 0 && (b.nextSlideTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        b.nextSlide()
    }, 1e3 * b.slideDelay))) : b.slideDelay > 0 && (b.nextSlideTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        b.nextSlide()
    }, 1e3 * b.slideDelay)), typeof b.onNextSlide == "function" && b.onNextSlide(b.currImg)
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.drawParticles = function () {
    var a = this,
        b = a.ctx.createImageData(a.cw, a.ch),
        c = b.data,
        d, e, f, g, h, i, j = a.pxlBuffer.first;
    while (j != null) {
        e = ~~j.x, f = ~~j.y;
        for (g = e; g < e + a.ptlSize && g >= 0 && g < a.cw; g++)
            for (h = f; h < f + a.ptlSize && h >= 0 && h < a.ch; h++) d = (h * b.width + g) * 4, i = typeof j.color == "function" ? j.color() : j.color, c[d + 0] = i[0], c[d + 1] = i[1], c[d + 2] = i[2], c[d + 3] = i[3];
        j = j.next
    }
    b.data = c, a.ctx.putImageData(b, 0, 0)
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.getPixelFromImageData = function (a, b, c) {
    var d = this,
        e = [];
    for (var f = 0; f < a.width; f += d.ptlGap + 1)
        for (var g = 0; g < a.height; g += d.ptlGap + 1) i = (g * a.width + f) * 4, a.data[i + 3] > 0 && e.push({
            x: b + f,
            y: c + g,
            color: d.monochrome == !0 ? [d.colorArr[0], d.colorArr[1], d.colorArr[2], d.colorArr[3]] : [a.data[i], a.data[i + 1], a.data[i + 2], a.data[i + 3]]
        });
    return e
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.init = function (a) {
    var b = this;
    if (b.imgs.length > 0) {
        b.$srcCanv.width = b.imgs[b.currImg].width, b.$srcCanv.height = b.imgs[b.currImg].height, b.srcCtx.clearRect(0, 0, b.$srcCanv.width, b.$srcCanv.height), b.srcCtx.drawImage(b.imgs[b.currImg], 0, 0);
        var c = b.getPixelFromImageData(b.srcCtx.getImageData(0, 0, b.$srcCanv.width, b.$srcCanv.height), ~~(b.cw / 2 - b.$srcCanv.width / 2), ~~(b.ch / 2 - b.$srcCanv.height / 2));
        if (b.showArrowControls == !0) {
            b.prevCtx.clearRect(0, 0, b.$prevCanv.width, b.$prevCanv.height), b.prevCtx.drawImage(b.imgControlPrev, 0, 0);
            var d = b.getPixelFromImageData(b.prevCtx.getImageData(0, 0, b.$prevCanv.width, b.$prevCanv.height), b.arrowPadding, ~~(b.ch / 2 - b.$prevCanv.height / 2));
            for (var e = 0, f = d.length; e < f; e++) d[e].color = function () {
                return b.mx >= 0 && b.mx < b.arrowPadding * 2 + b.$prevCanv.width ? b.hoverColorArr : b.colorArr
            }, c.push(d[e]);
            b.nextCtx.clearRect(0, 0, b.$nextCanv.width, b.$nextCanv.height), b.nextCtx.drawImage(b.imgControlNext, 0, 0);
            var g = b.getPixelFromImageData(b.nextCtx.getImageData(0, 0, b.$nextCanv.width, b.$nextCanv.height), b.cw - b.arrowPadding - b.$nextCanv.width, ~~(b.ch / 2 - b.$nextCanv.height / 2));
            for (var e = 0, f = g.length; e < f; e++) g[e].color = function () {
                return b.mx > 0 && b.mx > b.cw - (b.arrowPadding * 2 + b.$nextCanv.width) ? b.hoverColorArr : b.colorArr
            }, c.push(g[e])
        }
        if (b.currImg != b.lastImg || a == !0) c.shuffle(), b.lastImg = b.currImg;
        var h = b.pxlBuffer.first;
        for (var e = 0, f = c.length; e < f; e++) {
            var i = null;
            h != null ? (i = h, h = h.next) : (b.swapList(b.recycleBuffer.first, b.recycleBuffer, b.pxlBuffer), i = b.pxlBuffer.first), i.gravityX = c[e].x, i.gravityY = c[e].y, i.color = c[e].color
        }
        while (h != null) h.ttl = ~~(Math.random() * 10), h.gravityY = ~~(b.ch * Math.random()), h.gravityX = ~~(b.cw * Math.random()), h = h.next;
        b.$overlay.innerHTML = b.$$slides[b.currImg].innerHTML
    }
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.getCw = function () {
    var a = this;
    return Math.min(document.body.clientWidth, a.width, a.$container.clientWidth)
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.getCh = function () {
    var a = this;
    return Math.min(document.body.clientHeight, a.height, a.$container.clientHeight)
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.resize = function () {
    var a = this;
    a.cw = a.getCw(), a.ch = a.getCh(), a.$canv.width = a.cw, a.$canv.height = a.ch, a.init(!0)
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.setColor = function (a) {
    var b = this;
    b.colorArr = b.parseColor(a)
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.setHoverColor = function (a) {
    var b = this;
    b.hoverColorArr = b.parseColor(a)
}, ParticleSlider.prototype.requestAnimationFrame = function (a) {
    var b = this,
        c = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (a) {
            window.setTimeout(a, 1e3 / 60)
        };
    c(a)
};
```

I had updated the particle.js file to remove loading animation.try this..